# Could not open key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyAppAssembly

Tags: windows-xp, wix, registry, wix3.5

I created setup for my applicaiton using WIX 3.5. Installer works fine for first time. But after uninstalling application and then reinstalling again on same machine, I get following error message:

"Could not ope key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\XMyapp...\myapp. Verify that you have sufficeint access to that key or contact your support personnel."

During installation my msi is supposed to install this assembly. After uninstall i see that these registry enntries are removed...which is same as what it should be during first time install.

I am confused as why the installer is trying to open this registry entry??

I created 2 more installers using WIX 3.5 for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 but never found this problem. This is only with Windows XP SP3 box.

Please suggest any solution to this problem.

Following is partial code from my .wxs file generated by Heat.exe. I am getting error for TimeLimitPlugin class below

```
<Directory Id="dirE6F61FBBE33D607D42934C479509E1A7" Name="bin">
   <Component Id="cmp8862A7C3908D1BE33925BE0E72222A47" Guid="{EC21FA8F-ADAE-4608-8CB0-49B9EE7F5A37}">
   <File Id="fil143DAAA17C8B9650C00B50AB55BE85D3" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\OneApp31_deploy\Debug\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="cmp120CF12CD801404A02CE3906AD63E471" Guid="{46428AEB-4AD5-4230-A0DD-284C35682C0C}">                     
    <Class Id="{0155BEAB-D46E-3EC9-9535-263A90812041}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="TimeLimitPlugin" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
        <ProgId Id="TimeLimitPlugin" Description="TimeLimitPlugin" />
      </Class>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of WiX?  Are you prompted to restart your machine after uninstalling?  Have you tried to restart your machine before trying to re-install?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a per-user package (Package/@InstallScope="perUser" instead of Package/@InstallScope="perMachine"). When you install the `Class` element is writing to the HKCU CLSID registration location. I doubt it is the exact snippet above causing the issue but some other registration in your package.